# Set Context and Dependicie Injection on Netbeans (after project creation)

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, netbeans-7

I'm developing a J2EE project with NetBeans. 
When I created the project I didn't check the "Enable Contexts and Dependency Injection" option.

Is it possibile to change the option after the project creation? Where?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Steps -

1. Right-click your Project.
2. Go to `New` and then select `Others`.
3. From the `Categories` list, select `Contexts and Dependency Injection`.
4. Then on the right-hand side, from `File Types` list select `beans.xml (CDI Configuration File)`
5. Click Next and Finish leaving the file-name to defualt (i.e. beans).

That's it. It creates the beans.xml file and it's enough to tell Java EE-compliant server that your project is a module containing CDI beans.

I found this -

> The 'Enable Contexts and Dependency Injection' option, when selected, generates a beans.xml file in the project's WEB-INF folder when the project template is created. The beans.xml file is used by CDI to instruct the Java EE-compliant server that the project is a module containing CDI beans.

from [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/cdi-intro.html).